# Pandas Merge two column to another Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two columns to another dataframe based on Squad column
`df1`

```
    Squad
0   Arsenal
1   Aston Villa
2   Bournemouth
3   Brighton
4   Burnley
5   Chelsea
6   Crystal Palace
7   Everton
8   Leicester City
9   Liverpool
10  Manchester City
11  Manchester Utd
12  Newcastle Utd
13  Norwich City
14  Sheffield Utd
15  Southampton
16  Tottenham
17  Watford
18  West Ham
19  Wolves
```

`df2`

```
    Rk  Squad   MP  W   D   L   GF  GA  GD  Pts ... L   GF  GA  GD  Pts Pts/G   xG  xGA xGD xGD/90
0   1   Liverpool   19  18  1   0   52  16  36  55  ... 3   33  17  16  44  2.32    31.2    21.6    9.5 0.50
1   2   Manchester City 19  15  2   2   57  13  44  47  ... 7   45  22  23  34  1.79    45.5    19.5    26.0    1.37
2   3   Manchester Utd  19  10  7   2   40  17  23  37  ... 6   26  19  7   29  1.53    28.4    21.1    7.4 0.39
3   4   Chelsea 19  11  3   5   30  16  14  36  ... 7   39  38  1   30  1.58    29.2    27.2    2.0 0.10
4   5   Leicester City  19  11  4   4   35  17  18  37  ... 8   32  24  8   25  1.32    31.0    22.7    8.3 0.44
5   6   Tottenham   19  12  3   4   36  17  19  39  ... 7   25  30  -5  20  1.05    21.6    28.7    -7.1    -0.37
6   7   Wolves  19  8   7   4   27  19  8   31  ... 5   24  21  3   28  1.47    21.2    18.3    2.9 0.15
7   8   Arsenal 19  10  6   3   36  24  12  36  ... 7   20  24  -4  20  1.05    22.0    25.8    -3.8    -0.20
8   9   Sheffield Utd   19  10  3   6   24  15  9   33  ... 6   15  24  -9  21  1.11    15.3    28.2    -12.9   -0.68
9   10  Burnley 19  8   4   7   24  23  1   28  ... 7   19  27  -8  26  1.37    16.6    27.1    -10.4   -0.55
10  11  Southampton 19  6   3   10  21  35  -14 21  ... 6   30  25  5   31  1.63    30.8    24.9    5.9 0.31
11  12  Everton 19  8   7   4   24  21  3   31  ... 11  20  35  -15 18  0.95    21.8    24.9    -3.1    -0.16
12  13  Newcastle Utd   19  6   8   5   20  21  -1  26  ... 11  18  37  -19 18  0.95    15.0    30.3    -15.3   -0.81
13  14  Crystal Palace  19  6   5   8   15  20  -5  23  ... 9   16  30  -14 20  1.05    16.4    31.6    -15.2   -0.80
14  15  Brighton    19  5   7   7   20  27  -7  22  ... 8   19  27  -8  19  1.00    20.3    28.5    -8.2    -0.43
15  16  West Ham    19  6   4   9   30  33  -3  22  ... 10  19  29  -10 17  0.89    22.5    31.9    -9.4    -0.49
16  17  Aston Villa 19  7   3   9   22  30  -8  24  ... 12  19  37  -18 11  0.58    18.5    34.5    -16.0   -0.84
17  18  Bournemouth 19  5   6   8   22  30  -8  21  ... 14  18  35  -17 13  0.68    20.4    32.3    -11.9   -0.63
18  19  Watford 19  6   6   7   22  27  -5  24  ... 13  14  37  -23 10  0.53    18.5    29.9    -11.4   -0.60
19  20  Norwich City    19  4   3   12  19  37  -18 15  ... 15  7   38  -31 6   0.32    17.7    30.2    -12.6   -0.66
```

I want to create a new column on df1 and make a calculation that is, value of W column divide by value of MP column.
I tried to merge W column to df1 but I got `TypeError: Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray`

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2['Squad','W'], on='Squad',how='left')
```

Comment: `df2['Squad','W']` should be `df2[['Squad','W']]` or you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
result = df1.merge(df2[['Squad','W', 'MP']], how='left')
result['new_col'] = result['W'] / result['MP']
```

`NOTE:` Make sure to handle `NAN and 0` before dividing.